# How can this probability result be true? Is it not a contradiction?

Tags: probability

An exercise asks me to prove that given a sequence $X_n$ and some other $X$, and some $p > 0$, then if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E|X_n - X|^p$ is finite, then $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$.

But if that sum is finite, then the limit of $E|X_n - X|^p$ must be zero, which by definition implies $L^p$-convergence.

Hence, this is a very strong and simple relationship between almost sure convergence and $L^p$-convergence. And yet, I was told there was no such simple relationship, during the first lecture. The professor kept repeating that.

What's going on here? Am I just overthinking things and this relationship really is true, or what?

Comment: You are over *and* underthinking at once. True, the condition implies $L^p$ convergence of $X_n$ to $X$.  But that is not *all*  it implies.

Comment: When you see a convergent sum, you must think Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: What else does it imply?

Comment: Does $L^p$ convergence imply the condition though? Only then would you have a relationship between $L^p$ convergence and almost sure convergence. Otherwise, it is like saying that if $n=42$ then $n$ is both even and positive, so there is a strong and simple relationship between even integers and positive integers.

Comment: $L_p$ convergence just implies $E[|X_n-X|^p]\rightarrow 0$, not that the sum is finite.  For example suppose $E[|X_n-X|^p]=1/n$ for $n\in\{1, 2, 3,..\}$. So we have $L_p$ convergence but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E[|X_n-X|^p] = \infty$. If we know the sum is finite, that means a stronger result. To prove almost-sure convergence in general situations, it is enough to show that for all $\epsilon>0$ we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon] < \infty$ (which links to the Borel-Cantelli comment above).